# Where is this folder

Tags: images

I am very very new to wordpress.
I had a company set things up for me and now I am broke...so I am trying to make changes on my own.
I figured most stuff out, but I cannot find out how to access the image folder for the header of my site...I want to replace it with a new image that I am making.
When I click on the image and ask for the source it tells me that it is located here: http://healthbasedmeditation.com/wp-content/themes/maparaan/images/logo.png
But I logged into my wordpress account and I cannot find that folder anywhere.
Please help!

Comment: Unless there is the possibility at the backend/dashboard to replace that header image, but I guess you searched/checked for that, you have to access your server via FTP, e.g. with a program like [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/).

Comment: I can sympathise with you but gaining access to your server to upload a new logo.png is offtopic. Even then, if it were on topic, there's no way to answer this question as it's extremely server specific. You should look at your web hosts documentation and control panel or contact their support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to connect to your webserver via FTP, and navigate to that folder. That folder is not accessible via the WordPress admin utilities.